# RefineryCMS: app not running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, refinerycms

I did not add the `--heroku` option according to the [guides/heroku](http://refinerycms.com/guides/heroku). So I skipped to

**2 Deploying an existing local Refinery application**

And this is now my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'taps'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# Refinery CMS
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.0'

# Optionally, specify additional Refinery CMS Extensions here:
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', '~> 1.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-inquiries', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-search', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-page-images', '~> 2.1.0'

gem 'refinerycms-events', :path => 'vendor/extensions'
```

I already had an app created on Heroku. So I just ran the obvious `heroku git:remote -a rickrolling` and yes I did test it.

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:rickrolling.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:rickrolling.git (push)
```

I then did as instructed in

**2.3 Step 3: Set up asset precompilation**

Here is my `application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Rickrockstar
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
  end
end
```

Then I ran `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` and yes I verified what stack it was on

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ heroku stack
=== rickrolling Available Stacks
  bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
* cedar
```

Because I already had data that I wanted to push I followed

**2.5 Step 4 (Option 2): Copy your data from your local database to the Heroku app**

which said to and did `gem insall taps` and `heroku db:push` but I got this error

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ heroku db:push
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3      /sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0020 p:-545436774 s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 TOP
c:0019 p:---- s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 CFUNC  :require
c:0018 p:0036 s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0017 p:0029 s:0069 b:0069 l:000065 d:000068 BLOCK  /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-  p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0016 p:0035 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 TOP    /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2
c:0015 p:---- s:0064 b:0064 l:000063 d:000063 FINISH
c:0014 p:---- s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0089 s:0058 b:0058 l:000054 d:000057 BLOCK  /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60
c:0012 p:0158 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35
c:0011 p:0109 s:0048 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 TOP    /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/cli.rb:10
c:0010 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 FINISH
c:0009 p:---- s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 CFUNC  :require
c:0008 p:0036 s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0007 p:0040 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:208
c:0006 p:0011 s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 METHOD /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:24
c:0005 p:0046 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206
c:0004 p:0112 s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 METHOD /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28
c:0003 p:0232 s:0008 b:0008 l:0002a8 d:0003d8 EVAL   /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0002a8 d:0002a8 TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:24:in `push'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:208:in `load_taps'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/cli.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/pathname.bundle
   10 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   11 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/digest.bundle
   12 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
   13 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/etc.bundle
   14 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
   15 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/stringio.bundle
   16 /usr/local/heroku/lib/vendor/heroku/okjson.rb
   17 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb
   18 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb
   19 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parseexception.rb
   20 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/default.rb
   21 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/pretty.rb
   22 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/node.rb
   23 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/child.rb
   24 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parent.rb
   25 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmltokens.rb
   26 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/namespace.rb
   27 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/encoding.rb
   28 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/source.rb
   29 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/entity.rb
   30 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attlistdecl.rb
   31 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/doctype.rb
   32 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb
   33 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attribute.rb
   34 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/cdata.rb
   35 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/functions.rb
   36 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/syncenumerator.rb
   37 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/xpathparser.rb
   38 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath_parser.rb
   39 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb
   40 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb
   41 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmldecl.rb
   42 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/comment.rb
   43 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/instruction.rb
   44 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/rexml.rb
   45 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/output.rb
   46 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/undefinednamespaceexception.rb
   47 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
   48 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb
   49 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/streamparser.rb
   50 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/validation/validationexception.rb
   51 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb
   52 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb
   53 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
   54 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
   55 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
   56 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
   57 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
   58 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
   59 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
   60 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
   61 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
   62 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/date_core.bundle
   63 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
   64 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
   65 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
   66 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
   67 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
   68 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
   69 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
   70 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb
   71 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb
   72 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/plugin.rb
   73 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/version.rb
   74 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb
   75 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb
   76 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/ssl_endpoint.rb
   77 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client.rb
   78 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku.rb
   79 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb
   80 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
   81 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/socket.bundle
   82 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
   83 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb
   84 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb
   85 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/account.rb
   86 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/accounts.rb
   87 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb
   88 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb
   89 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb
   90 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb

  114 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon.rb
  115 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb
  116 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/config.rb
  117 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb
  118 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/domains.rb
  119 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/drains.rb
  120 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/cisaurus.rb
  121 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb
  122 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/git.rb
  123 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/deprecated.rb
  124 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/deprecated/help.rb
  125 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/help.rb
  126 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/keys.rb
  127 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/labs.rb
  128 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/log_displayer.rb
  129 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/logs.rb
  130 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/maintenance.rb
  131 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/heroku_postgresql.rb
  132 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb
  133 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb
  134 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb
  135 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/plugins.rb
  136 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/ps.rb
  137 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/regions.rb
  138 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/releases.rb
  139 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle
  140 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb
  141 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/sharing.rb
  142 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/ssl.rb
  143 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/stack.rb
  144 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/status.rb
  145 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/update.rb
  146 /Users/juan.gallardo/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/version.rb

  245 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/version.rb
  246 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/config.rb
  247 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/errors.rb
  248 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/chunksize.rb
  249 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb
  250 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/monkey.rb
  251 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart.rb
  252 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb
  253 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/vendor/okjson.rb
  254 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/multipart.rb
  255 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/log.rb
  256 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/data_stream.rb
  257 /Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Some lines are missing because I exceeded the character count. But the full file is at https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/6370370

And yes, I did try  `heroku restart` per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/VjjTQijkM6k

So tyring to figure out the next step from here. Not too savvy yet with interpretting the error reports.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would have thought having sqlite3 in there under the development group would be fine but the error is coming from Heroku trying to install sqlite3 and the sqlite3 gem is not compatible with Heroku. So, I'd try removing that from your Gemfile completely and seeing whether that helps.

Comment: Removed it, per your instructions. Here is the new errors from heroku logs https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/6371435

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly your gist links is not working but I am assuming you have an issue with dates columns.
Sqlite and postgresql don't handle **dates** the same way. So copying your data from your local sqlite database would be an issue.
You can reset your heroku db then run merge, and seed commands so you can see your app up and running.

> `heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm YOUR_APP_NAME`
>
> `heroku run rake db:setup`

Then you have to figure a way to populate your local data.